# SAPUI5 Wait for an Deferred-Object // wait for .done() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, sapui5, .when

I know there are several threads on this, but I think in SAPUI5 context no thread answers this general topic on deferred/sync calls in SAPUI5.
In My Controller I got :

```
  test : function() {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var sServiceUrl = '/sap/opu/odata/sap/xyz/MySet?$format=json';

    var post = $.ajax({
        url: sServiceUrl,
        type: "GET"
    });

    post.done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        dfd.resolve();
    });

    post.fail(function(){
        console.log("Error loading: " + sServiceUrl);
        dfd.reject();
    });

    return dfd.promise();

  },
```

in My view I am calling the method AND I want to wait for the result, how to I manage it correctly?

```
  var test = oController.test();
  console.log(test);
  $.when(test).done().then(console.log("finished"));
```

also this approach does not wait:

```
$.when(oController.test()).then(console.log("finished"));
```

As expected, test is undefined, "finished" is logged, and when .done from method is ready, it is logged. but I want to wait for it (and in best case return data from ajax back).. 
 how do I wait for post.done() to continue in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` operator invokes the function. You are invoking the function yourself, the function is not called by the `then` method. What happens is you call the `log` function and it's returned value is set as the handler. Since you want to pass an argument to the `console.log` method, you can use an anonymous function:

```
dfd.resolve(data);

// ...

$.when(oController.test()).then(function(data) {
    console.log('finished', data);
});
```

Comment: do you think its a problem to nest multiple then-functions? lets say 10 times, because I have to wait for several backend calls in a sequence?

Comment: @zyrex You could pass several deferred/promise objects to the `$.when`, then the `then` handler is called when all of them are resolved.